# Getting Media file attributes in Windows 8 c#

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, mp3, wma

Is there a generic way to get the media attributes like artist information etc in Windows 8? Or at least in classic .net C# open source code? I am looking right now for Audio file attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it seems to expose the [Windows Property System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff728898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can check these on MSDN:

- [StorageFile.Properties property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.properties.aspx)
- [StorageItemContentProperties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileproperties.storageitemcontentproperties.getmusicpropertiesasync.aspx)
- [MusicProperties class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileproperties.musicproperties.aspx)

Comment: That's the Windows Runtime/Metro Style Applications answer. Would you like one that works for desktop apps?